# Calculate Fourier Transform

Tags: complex-numbers

I have question for which i am stuck at

Calculate the Fourier Transform of $f(x) = e^-((x-1)^2)/4$

I am not sure if my answer is correct since it makes no sense...

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the question. Also show us your efforts on the problem to avoid this question being highly downvoted or being closed. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) link to know how to ask a good question on this website

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(x) = e^{\left(-\frac{1}{4} \, {\left(x - 1\right)}^{2}\right)} $$
applying the definition of the fourier transform yields
$$ \mathfrak{F} (\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 \, \pi x \xi - \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(x - 1\right)}^{2}}  dx $$
$$ = 2 \, \sqrt{\pi} e^{\left(4 \, \pi^{2} \xi^{2} - 2 \, \pi \xi\right)} $$